# How to send Prometheus Alerts to two different Alertmanagers

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

In my prometheus.yml configuration I already have an alertmanager setup and it's working. I want to add one more alertmanager in the configuration so that the prometheus alerts are sent to both alertmanagers. How can I achieve that?

```
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - scheme: http
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - 'alertmanager.projectii.io:9094'

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following configuration?

```
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - scheme: http
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - 'ALERTMANAGER-1:9094'
      - 'ALERTMANAGER-2:9094'
```